# How to avoid service multiple time run in hook using feathers.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs, feathers-hook, feathers-service

I'm facing problem in feathers service in feathers hook. Exactly the problem is i'm using feather service in feather hook and when i call service in hook it run multiple times so that memory issue is to be happen. my question is how to avoid service multiple run in hook.

```
function orders(hook){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
      hook.app.service('orders')
        .find(hook.app.query)
        .then(result => {
          resolve(result.data)
        }).catch(e =>{
        reject(e)
      })
  })
}
```

my expected solution is the service should be run in single time at hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service method ideally shouldn't call itself in a hook but if you do, you will need a breaking condition so that it doesn't keep calling itself in an infinite loop. This can be done by e.g. passing a parameter that will skip the self-referential call if it is not set:

```
app.service('myservice').hooks({
  before: {
    find(hook) {
      if(!hook.params.fromOtherHook) {

        const newParams = Object.assign({
          fromOtherHook: true
        }, hook.params);

        return hook.service.find(newParams);
      }
    }
  }
});
```